# RadGridView get child template data?

Tags: c#, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I am trying to get just the data for a child template when iterating through a grid.

I start with this:

```
        foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in radGridView1.Rows)
        {
            err = IterateChildRows(row);
        }
```

and pass the row to this:

```
    private bool IterateChildRows(GridViewRowInfo rowInfo)
    {
        bool err = false;
        if (rowInfo.Cells[5].Value != null && rowInfo.Cells[5].Value.ToString() != "01/01/1900")
        {
            if (rowInfo.Cells[0].ViewTemplate.Templates[0].Caption == "Current")
            {
                if (rowInfo.ViewTemplate.Templates[0].RowCount == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not all products have CURRENT quantity breaks", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    err = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return err;
     }
```

My problem is I can't seem to find just the child template data for the row I passed in. Everything I have tried seems to have ALL the child rows from all the master template items and not just the row I passed in.

So if I have 2 items in my main grid and 3 items each in my child template then I get a count of 6 and not 3.

I don't know where I am going wrong...

Anyone?

Cheers
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, the childrows are accessible through HierarchyRowInfo

```
private bool IterateChildRows(GridViewRowInfo rowInfo)
{
    bool err = false;
    GridViewHierarchyRowInfo hierarchyRow = rowInfo as GridViewHierarchyRowInfo;

    //To get current row childRows count
    int noOfChildRows = hierarchyRow.ChildRows.Count;

    //looping through the child rows
    foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in hierarchyRow.ChildRows)
    {   
        //check if its current child row
        if(row.IsCurrent)
        {
           // Do your logic
        }
    }

    return err;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Bayeni - I've been searching for this for a week... that was just what I was after :)

Comment: I'm glad to be help :)